# Write "latest" as version into package.json using npm

Tags: npm-install

If I write "latest" as the version of a package in the package.json, every call to `npm i` will download the latest version of the given package.

If I write something like `npm i -E somepackage@latest` it will not write "latest" into package.json, but the exact version that is the actual latest version.

Is there a way to force npm to write "latest" into the package.json? We are going away from the latest tag in package.json (please no good/bad practices answers).

I am just curious wether npm supports to do this or not...

Comment: npm install somepackage@latest --save or npm update?

Comment: @Potato, this does not work, if the latest version is like "1.2.3",it will write "^1.2.3" in the package.json. I am looking for a way to get npm to write "latest" explicitly...